# Pandas: How to mask first row after consecutive rows?

Tags: python, pandas

Given a Pandas data frame like

```
ID     VALUE
1      false
2      true
3      false
4      false
5      false
6      true
7      true
8      true
9      false
```

the result should be true for the next row following a group of true values

```
ID     RESULT
1      false
2      false
3      true
4      false
5      false
6      false
7      false
8      false
9      true
```

How to achieve this in Pandas?

Comment: can you explain the expected result little bit more?

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the `diff()` result of the `VALUE` column is equal to -1:

```
df.VALUE.astype(int).diff() == -1

#0    False
#1    False
#2     True
#3    False
#4    False
#5    False
#6    False
#7    False
#8     True
#Name: VALUE, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the values against an offset version to find where a new false is after trues:

```
>>> df['VALUE'] = df['VALUE'].astype('bool')
>>> (~df['VALUE'] & df['VALUE'].shift())

0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
5    False
6    False
7    False
8     True
Name: VALUE, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

values = ['false','true','false','false','false','true','true','true','false']
df = pd.DataFrame(values,columns=['values'])

print "Before changes: "
print df

to_become_false = df[df['values'] == 'true'].index.tolist()
to_become_true = [idx+1 for idx in to_become_false if not(idx+1 in to_become_false)]
df['values'][to_become_false] = 'false'
df['values'][to_become_true] = 'true'

print "\n\nAfter changes: "
print df
```

result :

```
Before changes: 
  values
0  false
1   true
2  false
3  false
4  false
5   true
6   true
7   true
8  false


After changes: 
  values
0  false
1  false
2   true
3  false
4  false
5  false
6  false
7  false
8   true
```